# Adobe experience design supports sketch file? Can I open Sketch file in XD?

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns, adobe, sketchapp

Is it possible to open sketch source file in adobe experience design. Does XD support sketch file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the latest version of XD supports sketch files. However, this feature has been relaesed recently and has many bugs.
It opens simple sketch files easily without anything breaking, but a complex sketch files may have problems.
Refer the following link for supported features

[Supported features when you open Sketch files in XD](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/kb/open-sketch-files-in-xd.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Adobe XD supports Sketch files. it includes these feature on March Update-
Refer this [link](https://www.adobe.com/in/products/xd/features.html?promoid=BMVV3DLX&mv=other) to know all the latest features and updates about Adobe XD
Now you can bring your Sketch designs and assets right into XD. Open your Sketch file from within XD and it automatically converts into an XD file so you don't have to start from scratch